# Navigation in Xamarin.Form from masterdetail page

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin and want to develop an Xamarin.Form Portable App.For that, I have created the project template as Xamarin.Form Portable.
After login, I have successfully created a Master Detail Page to display the Menu List like Home, AboutUs, ContactUs links in the left corner which is initially hide and when i click on the Menu Icon (Menu Icon is like three dashes(-) in parallel) all Menu List is populated to the right side in window. Now when i click on any Menu Item,I don't want to repeat the menu list or its icon in the inner pages. Instead of that, I want Navigation back arrow button instead of the Menu Icon. When I tried to navigate it like below it gives me error like "PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS/Android, please use a NavigationPage"

await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutUs());

If instead of this, I navigate it to the master detail page and set the About Us page as Detail property of the Master Detail Page then Menu Icon and Menu list will be reapeated which i don't want. Please help me how can i show the navigate the page with Back Arrow button in inner pages.

Overall, I want functionality like in Gmail where when we open any Detail of Email Menu button is not there but the back arrow button is there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach(Because DetailPage must be NavigationPage in Xamarin.Forms):

await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new AboutUs()));